# PHP GetHeaders() return keys in Uppercase on production server

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to get apikey in header. My problem is when i try to get that key, it gives me different parameter on both live server and local server.

**Code :**

```
$apikey = $this->request->getHeaders();
print_r($apikey);
```

**Local Result**

```
Array
(
    [Apikey] => *************
)
```

**Live Result :**

```
Array
(
    [APIKEY] => *************

)
```

See the KEY, on local I got **Apikey** first letter capital, on live **APIKEY** whole string is capital.

This creates a problem when i tried to access a key from an array.

Comment: You could write a function that will uppercase all keys... That way you know it's always uppercase...

Comment: That I know, But why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know I guess is might be a difference in the configuration files... What server are you using (Local and Live) ? What version ?

Comment: You mean php version? PHP 5.5 on both.

Comment: Apache version as well... Apache receives the Header then transmit them to PHP, so you need to check the config files for both programs, then check doc...

Comment: Can you please tell me the line which i need to check in config file? BTW Apache version is also same on both.

Comment: What exactly does `$this->request->getHeaders()` do...?

Comment: It'll fetch all the values from header and return an array.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but *how* does it do that? What library/class is it part of? Have you invented that function yourself, or is it part of something well known?

Comment: It's part of PHP framework, Phalcon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Still dont know why it occurs in some servers. So you could do:

$apikey = array_change_key_case(getHeaders(), CASE_LOWER);

This way you will always receive the keys in lowercase.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34659935)